# Is it possible to have a plot without any endpoints markers in NumberLinePlot?

Tags: plotting, numerics

I am using this code

```
list :=  {Interval[{ 1 , 1.5  }], Interval[{ 3.9 , 5.1 }], Interval[{ 5.7 ,6.7 }], Interval[{ 7.5 , 9.8 }] } ;

NumberLinePlot[list, Spacings -> Prepend[0.2]@ConstantArray[.0, Length@list], PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.001]]]
```

and I get this plot

[image]

**Question:**

> Is it possible to have a plot without any endpoints markers (I mean only a solid line of the intervals)? something like this picture
> [image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1.** You can add `PointSize[0]`  inside `Directive` when setting `PlotStyle`:

```
NumberLinePlot[list, 
 Spacings -> Prepend[0.2]@ConstantArray[.0, Length@list], 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, PointSize[0], Thickness[0.001]]]
```

[image]

**2.** You can post-process to remove `Point`s:

```
ReplaceAll[_Point -> Nothing]@
 NumberLinePlot[list, Spacings -> Prepend[0.2]@ConstantArray[.0, Length@list], 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.001]]]
```

[image]

**3.** Use `ReplaceAll[ _Point -> Nothing]` as the option value for [`DisplayFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DisplayFunction.html):

```
NumberLinePlot[list, 
 Spacings -> Prepend[0.2]@ConstantArray[.0, Length@list], 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.001]], 
 DisplayFunction -> ReplaceAll[ _Point -> Nothing]]
```

[image]

**4.** Use `LineOpacity -> 1` (to make lines rendered with opacity 1) and `Opacity -> 0` (to make all other primitives invisible) inside `Directive` when setting `PlotStyle`:

```
NumberLinePlot[list, 
 Spacings -> Prepend[0.2]@ConstantArray[.0, Length@list], 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, LineOpacity -> 1, Opacity -> 0, Thickness[0.001]]]
```

[image]